# Alternatives to rules engine for centralizing and maintaining rules

Tags: java, rules, drools, rule-engine

I'm trying to find an appropriate solution/framework to centralize and maintain rules. The number of rules is huge and they change frequently. I've gone through rules engines like Drools but find them unsuitable for reasons like the complexity of rules execution which affects maintainability and rules centralization overheads (rules engines often require another repository system to hold the rules).

The solution/framework I'm looking for should ideally allow me to write rules in standard programming languages such as Java with little overheads to centralizing and maintaining rules.

Big thanks in advance.

Comment: Most rules engines I have seen use DSL.  IMHO, The rules engines best programmed in Java are the super simple ones.  Perhaps you need a rules engine, or you don't really have rules, you just have an ordinary computer program which does stuff. (May be you have event driven programming in mind??)

Answer (score 1):

Drools 5.2.0 will have the new parser API, which - in theory - allows you to avoid DRL and write a rule engine's Left Hand Side (LHS) in Java, much like you'd write a JPA query with the JPA 2.0 criteria API.

Comment: Sound great, please let me know when is 5.2 going to be out? If you can also, do point me to some resources of how to use Drools to centralize and maintain rules without guvnor?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Spring support for [dynamic languages](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/dynamic-language.html)? You can invoke beans written in languages like Groovy or JRuby (I wrote JavaScript support some time ago if you care). Source code of these dynamic beans can be extracted into separate files which are scanned periodically to discover changes at runtime.

Much simpler, yet still powerful.

Comment: Changing rules at runtime is not so much a requirement for me, basically I need a solution/framework to help centralize and better maintain the rules.